# Identifying Multiple String in a Column then Outputting the Observation on a Separate Column; R v3.3.0

Tags: r, stringr

I have a sample data such as:

**current dataframe:**

```
Person <- c("John","Jacob","Jill","Joan") 
Fruits <- c("Apples","Apples,Oranges","Bananas","Oranges,Bananas")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Person,Fruits))
```

I am trying to identify if single fruit is contained in the string then put the name of the fruit on a separate column, if apple is listed with other fruits then "Apple & Other", or if there are multiple fruit (excluding apple) identify it as "Multiple" such that it appears as the following:

**wanted output:**

```
Person <- c("John","Jacob","Jill","Joan")
Fruits <- c("Apples","Apples,Oranges","Bananas","Oranges,Apples,Bananas")
Fruits2 <- c("Apples","Apples & Other","Bananas","Multiple")
df2 <- cbind(Person,Fruits)
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(df2,Fruits2))
```

I have tried using the following ifelse statement:

```
df$Fruits2 <- ifelse(grep("\\bApples\\b",df$Fruits),"Apples",
                 ifelse(grep(".Apples.|.Apples|Apples.",df$Fruits),"Apples & Other",
                        ifelse(grep("\\bOranges\\b",df$Fruits),"Oranges",
                               ifelse(grep(".Oranges.|.Oranges|Oranges.",df$Fruits),"Multiple",
                                      ifelse(grep("\\bBananas\\b",df$Fruits),"Bananas",
                                             ifelse(grep(".Bananas.|.Bananas|Bananas.",df$Fruits),"Multiple","TBD"))))))
```

However, the output of df$Fruits2 all becomes Output. Not sure if its the logic of the nested if statements, but if there is a better solution, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This if-else might be more concise for your logic, generally you go from most specific cases to more general cases, besides you will need `grepl` which returns logic values instead of `grep` which returns either integers or values as in the original vector:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Fruits2 = ifelse(grepl(",", Fruits), 
                        ifelse(grepl("Apples", Fruits), "Apples & Other", "Multiple"), 
                        Fruits))

#   Person          Fruits        Fruits2
# 1   John          Apples         Apples
# 2  Jacob  Apples,Oranges Apples & Other
# 3   Jill         Bananas        Bananas
# 4   Joan Oranges,Bananas       Multiple
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use strsplit() to split on "," and use ifelse to verify the conditions and use ur required strings to save in a new column.

```
  df$Fruits2 <- sapply(strsplit(df$Fruits,","),function(x){ifelse(length(x)==1,x[1], ifelse(length(x)>=2 & "Apples" %in% x, "Apples & Other","Multiple"))})

   df

   Person           Fruits         Fruits2
 1   John           Apples          Apples
 2  Jacob   Apples,Oranges  Apples & Other
 3   Jill          Bananas         Bananas
 4   Joan  Oranges,Bananas        Multiple
```